# intellijidea code completion not new variables

Tags: intellij-idea, code-completion

I'm using Android Studio and I have code completion enabled as in picture.

I have enabled "Autopopup code completion" and "Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc..".

I want to write:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(....);
```

I write "Dr", appears the popup, I click the space bar, and it writes "Drawable". It's all ok.

Then I write "d", appears the popup with "drawable" suggested, I  click the space bar, and it writes "drawable".

But I want to write "d".

Is it possible to change this option applying only to classes and methods and not to new variables?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to have code complete only apply to classes and methods and not to new variables. You have three options:

1. Turn off the Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc." options. You will then need to use <kbd>Enter</kbd> (to insert) or <kbd>Tab</kbd> (To overwrite) when you want to select an item from auto complete. The <kbd>.</kbd> (period/dot) key will still work when completing classes if you want to invoke a static member. (This is likely the best of the three choices and is the default behavior.)
2. After you type `d` for the variable name, hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the auto complete popup before you hit the <kbd>Space</kbd>.
3. Turn off "Autopopup code completion" so that you have to manually activate it each time via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>